# How does list generation with Fractionals work?

Tags: haskell, ghc

If i want to generate a list with the input:

```
[3.1,5.1..8.1]
```

GHC 8.6.3 returns:

```
[3.1,5.1,7.1,9.099999999999998]
```

*My problem here isn't the approximation of `9.1`, but why the list made by GHC has one element more than the following solution.*
 In the documentation I found in `GHC.Enum`, that `enumFromThenTo` translates this to something similar to the following:

```
    -- | Used in Haskell's translation of @[n,n'..m]@ with
    --   @[n,n'..m] = enumFromThenTo n n' m@, a possible implementation
    --   being @enumFromThenTo n n' m = worker (f x) (c x) n m@,
    --   @x = fromEnum n' - fromEnum n@, @c x = bool (>=) (<=) (x > 0)@
    --   @f n y
    --      | n > 0 = f (n - 1) (succ y)
    --      | n < 0 = f (n + 1) (pred y)
    --      | otherwise = y@ and
    --   @worker s c v m
    --      | c v m = v : worker s c (s v) m
    --      | otherwise = []@
```

So the following code:

```
import Data.Bool
eftt n s m = worker (f x) (c x) n m
     where x = (fromEnum s) - (fromEnum n)
c x = bool (>=) (<=) (x > 0)
f n y 
    | n > 0 = f (n-1) (succ y)
    | n < 0 = f (n+1) (pred y)
    | otherwise = y
worker s c v m
    | c v m = v: worker s c (s v) m
    | otherwise = []
```

On the same input as before, this however returns this list:

```
[3.1,5.1,7.1]
```

The  real implementation defined in `GHC.Enum` is the following:

```
enumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]
```

But there is no instantiation of `Enum Double` or `Enum Float` in `GHC.Enum`

So when I tried to reproduce this with the following code:

```
import Prelude(putStrLn,show)
import GHC.Enum(toEnum,fromEnum,Enum,enumFromThenTo)
import GHC.Base(map)

main = putStrLn (show (_enumFromThenTo 3.1 5.1 8.1))

_enumFromThenTo :: (Enum a) => a -> a -> a -> [a]
_enumFromThenTo x1 x2 y = map toEnum [fromEnum x1, fromEnum x2 .. fromEnum y]
```

I compiled with:

```
$ ghc -package ghc -package base <file.hs>
```

The result was again:

```
[3.0,5.0,7.0]
```

What is happening here, such that the output becomes:

```
[3.1,5.1,7.1,9.099999999999998]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Well, this is `instance Enum Double`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Float.html#line-677)

```
instance Enum Double where
  enumFromThenTo = numericEnumThenFromTo
```

[The implementation is here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Real.html#line-252)

```
numericEnumFromThenTo   :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => a -> a -> a -> [a]
numericEnumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3
    = takeWhile predicate (numericEnumFromThen e1 e2)
                                where
                                 mid = (e2 - e1) / 2
                                 predicate | e2 >= e1  = (<= e3 + mid)
                                           | otherwise = (>= e3 + mid)
```

More important than the implementation is the note above it:

```
-- These 'numeric' enumerations come straight from the Report
```

Which refers to [this passage in the (2010) Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4):

> For `Float` and `Double`, the semantics of the `enumFrom` family is given by the rules for `Int` above, except that the list terminates when the elements become greater than e<sub>3</sub> + i∕2 for positive increment i, or when they become less than e<sub>3</sub> + i∕2 for negative i.

(Where e<sub>3</sub> refers to the upper bound, and i the increment.)

The comment you found on `Enum` and the implementation in `class Enum` are both irrelevant. The comment is just example code detailing how an instance *might* be implemented, and the implementation given is inside a class, and thus may be overridden with anything.